# RedisClusterCommands scriptLoad()

Tags: kotlin, redis-cluster, lettuce

I'm using Lettuce lib to connect to Redis Cluster server and it got error when I try to call RedisClusterCommands.scriptLoad(). It throw exception:

```
io.lettuce.core.RedisException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:7004
    at io.lettuce.core.LettuceFutures.awaitOrCancel(LettuceFutures.java:129) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at io.lettuce.core.cluster.ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.handleInvocation(ClusterFutureSyncInvocationHandler.java:123) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:80) ~[lettuce-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.scriptLoad(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at com.slotty.common.services.redis.RedisManager.loadLuaScriptRaw(RedisManager.kt:106) ~[com.slotty.common-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.common.services.redis.RedisManager.loadLuaScript(RedisManager.kt:77) ~[com.slotty.common-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseServer.createServerStore(BaseServer.kt:154) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseServer.initStores(BaseServer.kt:150) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseZone.initStores(BaseZone.kt:163) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseServer.initServices(BaseServer.kt:87) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseZone.initServices(BaseZone.kt:49) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseServer.initialize(BaseServer.kt:65) ~[com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.slotty.core.server.BaseServer.init(BaseServer.kt:55) [com.slotty.core-2.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSExtensionManager.createExtension(SFSExtensionManager.java:303) [sfs2x.jar:?]
    at com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSZoneManager.createZone(SFSZoneManager.java:426) [sfs2x.jar:?]
    at com.smartfoxserver.v2.entities.managers.SFSZoneManager.initializeZones(SFSZoneManager.java:239) [sfs2x.jar:?]
    at com.smartfoxserver.v2.SmartFoxServer.start(SmartFoxServer.java:292) [sfs2x.jar:?]
    at com.smartfoxserver.v2.Main.main(Main.java:14) [sfs2x.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source) [i4jruntime.jar:?]
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.Launcher.main(Unknown Source) [i4jruntime.jar:?]
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:7004
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:665) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:665) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[?:1.8.0_102]
```

This is my initialize connection code: 
I tried to connect to redis server using RedisClusterClient. with IP 10.10.10.1 and port is 7000

```
    val redisUri = with(redisServiceInfo) {
                RedisURI.builder()
                        .withHost(host)
                        .also { if (password != null) it.withPassword(password) }
                        .withPort(port)
                        .withTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeout))
                        .build()
            }
            val clusterClient = RedisClusterClient.create(redisUri)      
            val connection = clusterClient.connect()       
            this.connection = connection
            this.clusterClient = clusterClient
```

Then I do a scriptLoad through RedisClusterCommands

```
shaResult = redisService.sync().scriptLoad(script)
```

My Redis Server have 6 nodes: 3 master 3 slave the port from 7000 -> 7002 is master, from 7003 -> 7005 is slave. The error is always happen on slave nodes after testing I found out that the connection is randomly return the URI with different host name, sometime it return **redis.domain.local** sometime it return **correct ip**, sometime it return **127.0.0.1**

I have tries to replace the IP of the nodes to 10.10.10.1 after connected to server and the function is work well.

Is there any config that I have missed when establish the connection?